# Dual screen monitor is cutting off half the other screen

Tags: drivers, nvidia, multiple-monitors

I build a new PC and am having some issues with the graphics when trying to set up dual monitors. I have the following configuration below:

[image: Monitor]

With this setup the right hand scree is completely black, if I flip them around the screen is cut off on both screens.

I am using a NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060, does anyone know how to fix this?